# Calling another widget's onClick method

Tags: android, onclick, widget, call, onclicklistener

How can I Call another widget's onClick() method while clicking an another?

for example when click on an EditText , it call a RaioButton's onClick method

```
et.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Calling rb.onClick();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to put the code that is executed inside onClick() into a **separate method** and call this method whenever you desire.

Like this:

```
et.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doStuff();
        }

rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doStuff();
        }

public void doStuff() {
 // do whatever you want here
}
```

If you really want to **fire another Views onClick method**, you can do it like this:

```
View.performClick();
```